# Why can't I use the file pointer after the first read attempt fails?

Tags: c, file

I want to open a file for reading and writing if it exists, or if not, create it and open it for writing.

The following code

```
FILE *file = fopen(argv[file_position], "r+");
if (!file) 
    file = fopen(argv[file_position], "w");
```

causes the error `file_name: Bad file descriptor`.

What is the cause of the error and how to avoid it?

Comment: You need to do some debugging and find out why the calls to `fopen` fail -- non-existent and/or permissions?

Comment: Which line causes the error?